# Responsive Table cell to new line

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

There's a third party content site that I have to "EMBED" via dynamic content, I don't know Ajax or Jquery at the moment so I am wondering if its possible to shift a table cell down to a new line essentially creating a new row.

The embed ends up with:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There were no classes or ID's placed in the table, however it is the only table on the page and it has way too much content to fit on one line, this is for a mobile website so I've got to make the whole page 320 pixels wide.

Is it possible using CSS alone?

I can't insert new HTML, the content is dynamically created from a secure server that we don't have access to, but we use an API key in order to access.. mediaqueries work though.

I'm currently trying to experiment with something along the lines of:

```
td {clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can set the `td` to `display:block;` then they'll all be under eachother.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td{
    display:block;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hDsts/

Comment: It's important to note that you have to have a doctype specified for this to work. I.e. <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Note that you have to give **both** `td`s the display block like shown above. I did oversee that, so this hint is for everyone like me ;) Also give both `td`s a width of 100% in case you modified them before.

Comment: If you add this in your CSS it will apply to **both** and **all** `<td>` elements as outlined in the answer. The only exception is if you write the style inline which is not in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Other solution (when `display: block;` not works) is to use `inline-block`:

**CSS**

```
td {
  display: inline-block;
}
```